# $f : \mathbb R \to \mathbb R, f(x) = x - 1 + e^{-x}$. Let sequence $(x_n)_{n \in \mathbb N} , x_0 \ge 0, x_n = f(x_{n-1})$. Prove $x_n$ is convergent.

Tags: calculus

$f : \mathbb R \to \mathbb R, f(x) = x - 1 + e^{-x}$.
Let sequence $(x_n)_{n \in \mathbb N} , x_0 \ge 0, x_n = f(x_{n-1})$. Prove $x_n$ is convergent and calculate $\lim_{n \to \infty}x_n$.

I am really disheartened, I just realized that I learned nothing in the past year that I tried to better myself at math, I don't know what to do, I keep asking questions here, get complicated answers, and the next time I come up across the same exercise I find I know absolutely nothing about it.

I understand what the exercise asks me to prove but I had no clue why it was true until I plotted the graph on desmos. In my mind, I thought this sentence was impossible, but only because I suck at math apparently. I realized, seeing the graph, that for any input $x \in (0, \infty)$ the output will be less than the input. So $f(x) < x$ for any $ x \ge 0$.

I would have never realized that by myself, and even now that I know it, I have no clue how to prove $x_n$ is convergent. Help me, please, I am losing my mind.

Comment: Hint: $ x_{n}\leq x_{n-1},x_{n}\geq 0 $

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***Simpler way***

Convergence can be obtained via the monotone convergence theorem by noting that the sequence $(x_n)$ is decreasing and bounded below by $0$ for any $x_0\geq 0$.

To prove that for any choice of $x_0$ the corresponding sequence $(x_n)$ converges to zero, one may argue as follows. We have already that $(x_n)$ converges, hence $(x_n)$ is Cauchy. It follows that $x_{n+1} - x_n \overset{n}{\longrightarrow} 0$. But $\displaystyle{x_{n+1}-x_n = \dfrac{1}{\mathrm{e}^{x_n}} - 1}$, completing the proof.

**Edit** (answer to comment). To show that $(x_n)$ is decreasing and bounded below by $0$, it suffices to prove that for any positive $x$ the inequalities  $0 < f(x) < x$ hold. Can you see why it suffices to prove this? (Hint: think of $x$ as the initial $x_0$). Try to also prove the inequalities.

***Harder way (more generally applicable)***

One may apply the unique fixed point theorem for the ordinary numerical iteration method, that is $x_n =f(x_n), n\in \mathbb{N}_+$. (Banach's fixed point theorem works just as well). Let $x_0>0$ be given. In order to apply the theorems in this case, one should first show that our $f$ is a contraction map on $[0, x_0]$ (continuity of $f$ is clear, and $[0, x_0]$ is complete). For this, it suffices to show that there exists a $c\in[0, 1)$ such that $|f'| < c$ in $[0, x_0]$.

But we have, for any positive real $x$, that $f'(x) = 1 - 1/\mathrm{e}^{x}$. This is strictly increasing for positive $x$, therefore $0\leq f'(x) < 1 - 1/\mathrm{e}^{x_0} =: c < 1$ in $[0, x_0]$. Note also that $f(0) = 0$ (in other words, $0$ is a fixed point of $f$ on $[0, x_0]$).

All that remains to show is $f([0, x_0]) \subseteq [0, x_0]$. Can you do this, completing the proof?

Comment: I don't know a lot of notations used in the "Harder way". I am used to prove a series is convergent by showing that it is monotone and bounded. The "Simpler way", which is the way that I was used to solving such problems, is not so simple for me. How do I show that $x_n$ is decreasing and bounded when I have no concrete values for $x_n$ other than a recurrence relation between consecutive terms of the series?

Comment: @RaduGabriel I have added some hints to the part "Simpler way". If anything is still unclear, don't hesitate to tell me. As for the harder part, if you quote some unfamiliar notation more specifically, I can try to explain.

Comment: I really appreciate your answer. I am aware why proving that would suffice, I just don't know how to even start to prove it, I didn't do this before. I usually look at the difference $x_{n+1} - x_n$ to tell if the series is increasing or decreasing and try to tell the bounds from there. Here I have no terms to work with, I am confused.

Comment: @RaduGabriel No problem. Let's start with the first inequality, namely that for any postive number $x$, we have $0 < f(x)$. Hint: what is $f(0)$? For positive real numbers, is $f$ (strictly) increasing, decreasing or something else? If we have a differentiable function with elementary derivatives, how can one study the monotonicity properties of a function?

Comment: I know that $f(x)$ is increasing for $x \in (0, \infty)$ and $ 0 \lt f(x)$ for $x \in (0, \infty)$. And my guess is that this function has a slant asymptote as well, probably $y = x - 1$. That would be enough to prove that $f(x) < x$ for any $x \ge 0$, right?

Comment: Because $f(0) = 0$ (easy to check by substitution, could also try to guess solutions to $f(x) = 0$) and $f$ being strictly increasing for positive reals (because derivative is strictly positive for positive reals) does indeed give $0<f(x)$ for any positive $x$. (1/3)

Comment: The function $f$ does indeed have an slanted asymptote, and $x - 1$ should be its equation. However, generally speaking, this would not be enough to prove $f(x) < x$ because $f$ could really start approaching its asymptote later on, after some postive $x'$, or it could be an "oscillatory" asympote (meaning that $f$ could, in theory, oscillate around the straight line $x - 1$ with oscillations going to $0$ as $x$ goes to $+\infty$. But the early oscillations (again in theory) could well be over the line $y = x$. (2/3)

Comment: @RaduGabriel To prove $f(x) < x$ for any positive $x$, you could begin by substituting $f(x)$ into this inequality. (Or, assume the contrary, that there exists some positive $z$ such that $f(z) \geq z$, and substitute our $f(z)$ into this inequality). After simplifying, what do we get from this? (3/3)

Comment: $e^{-z} > 1$. It is not true for $z \gt 0$. I can't believe it was this easy. I really appreciate your patience, you helped me tremendously <3.

Comment: Also I didn't know the function can oscillate around the asymptote. if the function has an asymptote doesn't that mean it $ y = a$ doesn't that mean the function will never touch it?

Comment: Also, I think I got too excited about this little "proof" you helped me with and forgot about the whole convergence thing. Now that I know $f(x) < x$ for any $x \gt 0$. Is this enough to just say $x_n$ converges? I mean I see that it converges, but in an exam would this suffice?

Comment: (1) I think you meant to write $x$ instead of $z$ there (if you were consistant with the notation I gave in my earlier comment)? (2) Yes, a function can intersect its asymptote; in fact, there a function may intersect its asymptote infinitely many times (even in the limit process itself). An example of this behavior would be $g(x) = \dfrac{\sin{x}}{x}$ which has the horisontal asymptote $x = 0$ as $x$ goes to $\pm\infty$.

Comment: (3) It depends on the exam, I guess. $0<f(x)<x$ does indeed suffice to prove that $(x_n)$ converges but you should be able to show the complete argument *why it suffices* when asked to do so. Note that this does *not*, however, prove that $x_n$ goes to $0$ as $n$ goes to $+\infty$ (for any $x_0\geq 0$). It just proves that $x_n$ converges to some value $L$ and this $L$ could depend on inital choice of $x_0$. The harder part proves both convergence of $(x_n)$ for any $x_0$ and that that convergence is always to $0$ (independent of choice of $x_0$).

Comment: @RaduGabriel No problem, and glad I could help!

Comment: @RaduGabriel I have also added another argument for $x_n$ always converging to $0$. Hope it helps.